# Div на всю оставшуюся часть страницы

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два div'а, один занимает 70px начиная с верхней части страницы и все по ширине, а второй должен занимать ВСЮ оставшуюсь часть страницы по длине и ширине. Как это установить?

```
.upper-part {background-color: green; height: 70px;} - первый div;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wqeg53g5/

1. делаем всем родительским элементам `height: 100%`
2. делаем необходимому врапперу `min-height: 100%`
3. с помощью отрицательного margin сдвигаем его на высоту .upper-part
4. внутреннему врапперу этот сдвиг компенсируем с помощью padding.

Answer (score 0):

```
.upper-part {
    background-color: green; 
    height: 70px;
}
.lower-part {
    background-color: red; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 70px; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lj0j0pz/)

Если потребуется устанавливать `margin` , то необходимо использовать `left` или `right` вместо него для второго слоя.